# Header wrong when using endnotes package

Tags: endnotes

Hello: I am using `\usepackage{endnotes}` with `\let\footnote=\endnote` in a two-sided book document class. When I type `\theendnotes` at the end of a chapter, all works well except that, in the header, the text "Notes" appears on both even and odd pages, whereas I'd rather have the chapter name on the left (even page) and Notes on the right only (odd page). It works with sections names, which always appear on the right (odd pages). 
Thanks a lot for your help (and I hope this is clear--first time I'm using this forum)!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Can you make a small example (MWE), which shows the problem?

Answer (score 2):

When `endnotes` defines its section heading, it sets both the left and right marks to the note name, which is why you get the behaviour you describe.  With the standard `book` class and no other headings formatting, the it suffices to do the following:

```
\documentclass[twoside]{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{endnotes}
\let\footnote=\endnote
\makeatletter
\def\enoteheading{\section*{\notesname
  \markright{\MakeUppercase{\notesname}}}%
    \@afterindenttrue
}
\makeatother
% Following command to produce dummy text and notes
\newcommand{\lipnote}{\lipsum*\footnote{\lipsum}\par}

\begin{document}
\chapter{A chapter}
\section{A section}
\lipnote
\lipnote
\clearpage
\theendnotes
\end{document}
```

[image: Even page header]
[image: Odd page header]