# Headings in endnote

Tags: endnotes

I want to produce two versions of a book, one with footnotes and the other with endnotes. I'm using the endnote package to convert the footnotes to endnotes to produce the second version. But I need to alter the text on the heading and get the headers on each page to look the same for the endnotes as the other chapters in the book. For example, currently the heading says "Notes", say I wish to change this to "Myheading which is underlined" and then have "something else" appear in the headers of the pages on which the endnotes themselves appear. Is there a simple way to do this?

Thanks

Comment: Does [this](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/262222/5872) help?

Answer (score 2):

I saw the crosspost to [LaTeX-Community.org](http://latex-community.org/forum/) earlier and already answered there. So I copy my shortened answer to here now.

The relevant definition in `endnotes.sty` is:

```
\def\notesname{Notes}%
\def\enoteheading{\section*{\notesname
  \@mkboth{\MakeUppercase{\notesname}}{\MakeUppercase{\notesname}}}%
  \mbox{}\par\vskip-\baselineskip}
```

You see, a standard section without numbering would be used, and the headers are set, but with `\MakeUppercase`. You could remove it in a redefinition.

So, redefinitions may look like, in your own preamble:

```
\renewcommand*{\notesname}{Myheading}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\enoteheading}{%
  \section*{\notesname}%
  \markboth{\notesname}{\notesname}%
  \@afterindenttrue}
\makeatother
```

Your end notes may then look like the other headings in your document, with default article settings like:

[image: sample output]

Complete thread: [headings in endnote](http://latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=44&t=26598).

Comment: This is basically a duplicate of my answer linked in the comments. [Header wrong when using endnotes package](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/262112)

Comment: @AlanMunn It's similar with some small differences. The OP also wanted to know how to redefine the header "Notes" to "Myheading" or so which isn't cover in the other post. Anyway, I thought instead of a link-only remark stating the cross-post location I thought it would be better to post the relevant stuff here, for completeness or being self-contained. But feel free to delete or to close, I don't worry.