# page headers for enotez with scrbook

Tags: koma-script, enotez

I have tried the solution from [Header wrong when using endnotes package](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/262112/header-wrong-when-using-endnotes-package). I have adapted it to `enotez` and use it with `KOMA scrbook` documentclass.

unfortunately, there seem not to be an effect on the page headers. with the original solution  with endnotes the right headers were changed to "Notes" but the right headers were still the last chapter.

I would like that after `\printendnotes` the effect is the same as with `\bibliography` which puts the same page header "bibliiography" left and right.

What is the best solution?

here the MWE

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\KOMAoptions{paper=      
    128.5mm:198.4mm, %(5,06" x 7,91")  %ziel
    DIV=9,  %ziel kleines buch 
    fontsize=12pt,
    headings=normal,
}


%%%% Sprache
\usepackage[german]{babel}  %scheint 

\usepackage{lipsum}
%\usepackage{endnotes}
\usepackage{enotez}
\let\footnote=\endnote
\makeatletter
\def\enoteheading{\section*{\notesname
        \markright{\MakeUppercase{\notesname}}}%
    \@afterindenttrue
}
\makeatother
% Following command to produce dummy text and notes
\newcommand{\lipnote}{\lipsum*\footnote{\lipsum}\par}

\begin{document}
    \chapter{A chapter}
    \section{A section}
    \lipnote
    \lipnote
    \clearpage
%   \theendnotes
        \printendnotes

\end{document}
```

Comment: `\markright{right}` only sets the right mark. If you want to set both right and left mark use `\markboth{left}{right}`

Comment: unfortunately, the settings in the `\def\enoteheading...` seems not to have any effect. I assume that the keywords for `enotez ` are different and the ones I use are specific for `endnotes` . I checked the documentation for `enotez` but could not find any hint.

Comment: Do you only want the marks correctly set or do you also want an entry in the toc?

Comment: at the moment I prefer no entry in the ToC, but could live with it (may even prefer it in the future).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`enotez` does not know `\enoteheading` but that is not surprising: it is not mentioned in the manual at all. It does have two optione, though, both described in the manual:

- `list-name = {<list name>}` The name of the notes list that used for the heading of the list.
- `list-heading = {<sectioning command including argument>}` You can use this option to manually set the list heading command, e. g., `list-heading = {\chapter{#1}}` for a numbered heading.

You can use this to set ´\markboth` for both left and right header:

```
\setenotez{list-heading=\chapter*{#1}\markboth{#1}{#1}}
```

In your example:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\KOMAoptions{
  paper=128.5mm:198.4mm, %(5,06" x 7,91")  %ziel
  DIV=9,  %ziel kleines buch 
  fontsize=12pt,
  headings=normal,
}

\usepackage[german]{babel}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{enotez}
\setenotez{list-heading=\chapter*{#1}\markboth{#1}{#1}}

% Following command to produce dummy text and notes
\newcommand{\lipnote}{\lipsum*\endnote{\lipsum}\par}

\begin{document}

\chapter{A chapter}
\section{A section}
\lipnote
\lipnote

\clearpage
\printendnotes

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the help! Your suggestion worked perfect and I marked it as solution.